# regex - pattern partially matching but not entirely by skipping pattern

Tags: regex

I have a block of html code in a file.  I have a class that I'm using called **highlight-address** to locate the text in a very large html file.   I'm looking for all text in between the >City, St zip<  It finds all 4 occurrences in the file but for some reason I'm not sure why it returns only 2 of the desired values.  It seems to ignore the desired regex and moves to something past it.

REGEX: highlight-address[\S\s]*?>(.*)</p>

```
desire: 'City1, ST 12345', 'City2, ST 67891', 'Parm=a, ST 11121', 'City4, ST 31415'
actual: 'City1, ST 12345', '2,245 sqft</span>', '2,378 sqft</span>', 'City4, ST 31415'
```

see demo: https://regex101.com/r/nd1cdu/1

? how do I fix the regular expression to capture the desired text?

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: sorry how do I do that? and is regex not able to do this? since all my code is regex based.

Comment: You can make the dot match a newline using the `s` flag and use a non greedy match. Or use `highlight-address[^<>]*>=?([^<>]*)<\/p>` https://regex101.com/r/4u65Hf/1

Comment: @The fourth bird - definitely closer.  But it still captures the \n is there a way to get rid of the \n then it would be perfect!!

Comment: You can remove the newlines from the capture group 1.

Comment: @The fourth bird - sorry I'm not following what would I need to modify?

Comment: The value that you want is in capture group 1 (highlighted in green in the regex101 link) You can get that value, and replace the newlines with an empty string, as the newlines are in the whole part that you are looking for.

Comment: @The fourth bird - sorry I'm quite new to regex. Is there a way to explain your highlight-address[^<>]*>=?([^<>]*)<\/p>. then maybe I can modify it easier. Thank you for your help.  It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @The fourth bird -  I'm using python

Comment: I think it would be easier to use beautiful soup with `soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('p', class_='3D"highlight-address"'):
    print(tag.text)`

Comment: @The fourth bird - thanks.  can you recommend any good sources to learn beautifulSoup?

Comment: @Lacer See this page for documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Appreciate the reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better option to use BeautifulSoup, and afterwards remove the newlines preceded by an optional equals sign.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('p', class_='3D"highlight-address"'):
    print(re.sub(r"=?[\r\n]+", "", tag.text))
```

Output

```
City1, ST 12345
City2, ST 67891
Parma, ST 11121
City4, ST 31415
```

Comment: It surely is a better idea - ++